# Display response-string in a Textview in a fragment

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, textview, fragment

I´m getting stucked on a - probably - "easy" problem... 
I´ve got a fragment which displays a TextView.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rezepte_test, container, false);

    TextView responseTV = (TextView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.tv_response);

    return inflatedView;
}
```

Next I´ve got a `private void` GET-Method, whose response body I want to display in this

```
String responseBody = response.body().string();
responseTV.setText(responseBody);
```

Everytime the Fragment will open, the app crashes caused by a NPE

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance

Comment: In what lifecycle method are you calling `responseTV.setText(responseBody);`?

Comment: Post your `fragment_rezepte_test.xml` please

Answer (score 0):

I am not very clear about the question and also not clear that exactly when you are trying to call this method response.body(), but please check whether your responsebody string is null or not and also use method isAdded() in case of fragments in every important method.
Edit : try to initialize that text view inside onActivityCreated and then use it.

Comment: Short: I want to print my response.body in the TextView. System.print shows me the string, so at least I´ve got a response.. But how do I get this in my TextView?

Comment: If I call the `responseTV.setText("Hello")` the "Hello" gets displayed... so the problem is probably in my `get-method`...

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to call super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)

View inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rezepte_test, container, false);

TextView responseTV = (TextView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.tv_response);

return inflatedView;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your xml layout (fragment_rezepte_test.xml)? Make sure you have a TextView with the same id.

Comment: this was the first I checked.. ;)